# Which model of Consumer Behavior has proven to have better predictive ability for complex products?

Tags: consumer-psychology

I read about several models in [Dr. Jeff Bray](https://scholar.google.co.uk/citations?user=eVhFe7kAAAAJ&hl=en)’s unpublished article ([Bray, 2008](http://eprints.bournemouth.ac.uk/10107/1/Consumer_Behaviour_Theory_-_Approaches_%26_Models.pdf)).

Does anyone know which of them has proven to have the better predicting ability? I mean, which of them holds more evidence of predictability so far?

I do not want to  be reading wild theories with little scientific grounding and it would be helpful is someone with the expertise on the subject could tell me which has more evidence grounding it.

The models of which the paper speaks are:

1. Consumer decision model.
2. Theory of buyer behavior.
3. Theory of reasoned action.
4. Theory of planned behavior.

Again, I'm not asking for explanation. I am asking which holds better evidence.

### Reference

Bray, J. P. (2008). Consumer behaviour theory: approaches and models. *Unpublished*
Retrieved from: [http://eprints.bournemouth.ac.uk/10107/1/Consumer_Behaviour_Theory_-*Approaches*%26_Models.pdf](http://eprints.bournemouth.ac.uk/10107/1/Consumer_Behaviour_Theory_-_Approaches_%26_Models.pdf)

Comment: Could you list and describe the models to help us answer your question?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE! I think that it would be unfair in a way for anyone to ask you to list all the models described by Dr. Bray when there are 25 pages of models to go through, but at the same time, to me it is a big ask for someone to go through the 33 page article and appraise each and every model.  Is there any particular model you have any issue with?  Maybe you could briefly describe the model for us and the issue you have with it and we can see how we can help.  As it stands this question is extremely broad.

Comment: @ChrisRogers no one is asking to list all the models and I do not think that my question is about fairness either. I'm asking for an expert on the subject, who could at first glance tell me which model has the more predictive ability, which is a measure of scientific quality. I'm not asking this because I want someone to do my homework, but because in such a young science I think it would be helpful for an expert to tell me where to start. I do not want to read wild theories if they do not have scientific grounding and that is why I am asking for an expert opinion.

Comment: @Seanny123 listed Seanny :) thanks.